# Building Android app using ANT, java resource files not in final apk?

Tags: android, ant, resources

I use a Java library that has a .xml file embedded, and uses this in the code using
`Library.class.getResourceAsStream("file.xml")`.

When I build with `eclipse`, everything goes fine. When I build with `ant` (without proguard), the resource can't be found when running the app.

After some searching it turns out that the .xml file didn't got added to the bin/classes folder. So I added a copy action after the `javac` command in the `build.xml` file.

```
<copy todir="${out.classes.absolute.dir}">
    <fileset dir="${lib_src}/src" includes="**/*.xml" />
</copy>
```

This works, in the sense that the xml files are now present in the `classes` folder. However, they do not get included in the final apk package.

What is going wrong here? Which build-action do I need to modify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by making the library android-only, not generic java. I added the xml file in the `resources` dir, I think it was in the `raw` dir or the `xml` dir. Then I used the standard android way to get those resources.

Comment: Can you explain more please? What does it mean to make it android-only? and how?

Comment: Making it a android library project. Simply create a android library project and add the java source files to the src folder. Then reference the library from your android app.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your /tools/ant/main_rules.xml file. This is the main build file that Android uses for its Ant builds. According to this, you should have your library files in a folder called "libs".

In any case it is a good idea for you to go through that xml file. It will explain in detail, what happens when you do commandline Ant builds.

Comment: Yes, I have copied that one in my custom build.xml. As per instructions. I however, can't find where in the process it's going wrong. Should the dexing add the .xml files into the dex for example?

Comment: If you set the libs folder correctly, your xml files should have been packaged into the apk. This will require troubleshooting, I think you can put Ant <echo> task in main_rules.xml to print out values and understand what is happening.